# animate opacity in IE on hover wont work

Tags: internet-explorer, animation, hover, opacity

I have a PNG that comes in to help read the menu on hover, but the fade wont work on IE,  It works great in Chrome and Firefox,  I have used PNG-24 as well and PNG-8  nothing is working

```
$(function() {
      $('#gradient').animate({ "opacity": 0 });

        $('#menu').hover(function() {
            $('#gradient').removeClass('hidden').animate({opacity: '1'}, 400);
        }, function() {
            $('#gradient').animate({filter: '0'}, 400);
        });
    });    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

IE at least older versions has serious problems combining PNG transparency and CSS transparency.

I think this is fixed in IE9 but I am not sure.

Each on their own works fine but not on the same image object.

Answer (score 0):

IE8 and lower do not support the standard CSS `opacity` attribute.

It does support an alternative method of opacity, using the IE-specific `filter` attribute, but it is a lot more complex to work with than `opacity`, since `filter` deals with a whole range of effects.

However, since you're using JQuery, why don't you use the built-in `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` effects instead - that way, JQuery does all the work for you, including working out how to change the opacity in the browser it's in.

See http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: i switched the code to  $(document).ready(function() {
  
            $('#menu').hover(function() {
                $('#gradient').fadeIn('slow');
            }, function() {
                $('#gradient').fadeOut('fast');
            });
        });    
   but it still doesnt fade